# Where can I find unit tests for regular expressions in multiple languages?

Tags: java, php, javascript, .net, regex

I'm building a regex helper at http://www.debuggex.com. The amount of detail I want to show requires me to write my own parser and matcher.

To make sure my parser and matcher work correctly, I've written my own unit tests for the Javascript flavor of regexes, but these only cover edge cases I know about. I would like to use a standard test suite, and was recently pointed to http://hg.ecmascript.org/tests/test262/summary, which I will be using.

My question is, where can I find such test suites for other regex flavors? I'd like to support other flavors in the future. I have not been able to find anything by googling ("test" pollutes the results with regex testers). I am looking for test suites for the languages **python**, **php**, **perl**, **java**, **ruby**, and **.net**.

Comment: Cool project! For starters, Python has [unit tests for its `re` module](https://github.com/jonashaag/cpython/blob/master/Lib/test/re_tests.py).

Comment: Good job on the debuggex! It's great!

Comment: That's really cool, great job.

Comment: [regexbuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/) is a nice tool !

Comment: Would it be possible for you share the unit tests you mentioned you created for the JS flavor of regex?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot make my tests public.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Most of those languages are open source.  Any decent project should have their test cases in said repo, otherwise I would be pretty concerned.

- [Python](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/178075fbff3a/Lib/test/re_tests.py)'s regex tests
- [PHP](https://github.com/php/php-src/tree/master/ext/pcre/tests)'s regex tests
- [Perl](http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl5.git/tree/HEAD:/t/re)'s regex tests looks really extensive
- [Open JDK](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u6/jdk/file/8c2c5d63a17e/test/java/util/regex/)'s unit tests (an open source flavour of Java)
- [Ruby](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/master/test/ruby/test_regexp.rb)'s regex tests
- [Mono](https://github.com/mono/mono/tree/0f2995e95e98e082c7c7039e17175cf2c6a00034/mcs/class/System/Test/System.Text.RegularExpressions)'s regex tests (open source version of .NET)
- [.NET Core](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/tree/master/src/libraries/System.Text.RegularExpressions/tests)'s regex tests
- [RE2](https://github.com/google/re2/tree/master/re2/testing)'s tests (C++ regex engine developed at Google)
- [C](https://github.com/att/ast/tree/2012-08-01-master/src/cmd/re) test suite (developed by AT&T Research)
- [PCRE](http://vcs.pcre.org/pcre2/code/trunk/testdata/) regex tests (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions C library)
- [JavaScript](https://github.com/tc39/test262/tree/master/test/built-ins/RegExp) regex tests (Ecma Technical Committee 39 compatability suite)

I also found an extensive chart on [this page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html) which might be of some help to you.

Comment: OpenJDK *is* Java, not really flavour thereof. (The official JDK is based on development in OpenJDK, with the addition of some closed-source code, so the builds might not be 100% compatible, but the regex engine should be the same in both.)

Comment: Not correct that .NET is closed source.  The sources are available at http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx.  You have to dig down from there to find specific parts though.

Answer (score 11):

To have a complete list on one page, I've found the ones omitted from the accepted answer:

- [Mono's](https://github.com/mono/mono/tree/0f2995e95e98e082c7c7039e17175cf2c6a00034/mcs/class/System/Test/System.Text.RegularExpressions) regex tests (it's an open source version of .net)
- [PHP's](https://github.com/php/php-src/tree/master/ext/pcre/tests) regex tests

Comment: Mono is an open source version of .Net. It has compilers for C# and F#, NOT VB.Net. On a personal note VB.Net is an abomination.

Comment: Updated answer to reflect your comment.

Comment: @SergiuToarca why not edit the accepted answer and add them there, so we'd have a complete list in one answer?

Comment: Because SO's point system strongly incentivizes me to add my own answer :P However, I've edited the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Additional regex test suites for additional languages:

- [D's standard library regex tests](https://github.com/dlang/phobos/tree/master/std/regex/internal) (look for `tests.*d` files)
- [Go's regex tests](https://golang.org/src/regexp/) (look for `.*test.*go` files)
- [GNU grep's tests](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/tree/tests) (Command line C regex engine)
- [regex-posix-unittest](https://wiki.haskell.org/Regex_Posix#regex-posix-unittest) (POSIX regex test suite written in Haskell)
- [ICU's regex tests](https://github.com/unicode-org/icu/tree/master/icu4c/source/test/testdata) (C/C++ and Java libraries for Unicode, look for files named `re[_g].*txt`)
- [Rust's regex tests](https://github.com/rust-lang/regex/tree/master/tests)
- [TCL's regex tests](https://github.com/tcltk/tcl/tree/master/tests) (look for the `reg.*test` files)
- [TRE's regex tests](https://github.com/laurikari/tre/tree/master/tests) (C regex engine which aims for strict POSIX compliance)
- [V8's regex tests](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/master/test/mjsunit/) (V8 is the JavaScript engine of Chrome, search for files named `.*regexp.*js`)
- [WebKit's regex tests](https://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/LayoutTests/fast/regex) (JavaScript tests are in script-tests folders)
- [Yarr's regex tests](https://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/JSTests/regexp/RegExpTest.data) (C++ regex engine of WebKit's JavaScriptCore)

### Bonus

- [Regfuzz](https://code.google.com/p/regfuzz/) (C toolkit for testing regular expression robustness using randomly generated and invalid regexes)