# JavaScript regular expression rule is breaking ASP.NET minification

Tags: javascript, asp.net, regex

I have this function, and it works fine in all browsers:

```
    cleanKey = function( key ){
        return key.replace( /[^-._0-9A-Za-z\xb7\xc0-\xd6\xd8-\xf6\xf8-\u037d\u37f-\u1fff\u200c-\u200d\u203f\u2040\u2070-\u218f]/g, "-" );
    };
```

However, my ASP.NET MVC 3 project throws a regular expression syntax error when trying to minify that code:

> run-time error JS5017: Syntax error in regular expression
>   /[^-._0-9A-Za-z\xb7\xc0-\xd6\xd8-\xf6\xf8-\u037d\u37f-\u1fff\u200c-\u200d\u203f\u2040\u2070-\u218f]/g

Comment: I took the liberty of editing your question, since I believe the previous draft of you question was better: it also included the js-code, the relevant error-number and error-message (useful for future google searches) and pointed out (correctly) that the regex *does* work in most browers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to try `\u037f` instead of `\u37f` since [MSDN specifies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ae5bf541%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

> **\xn**
>   Matches n, where n is a hexadecimal escape value.
>   Hexadecimal escape values must be exactly two digits long.
>   *For example, '\x41' matches "A".   '\x041' is equivalent to '\x04' & "1".*
>   Allows ASCII codes to be used in regular expressions.
>
> **\un**
>   Matches n, where n is a Unicode character *expressed as four hexadecimal digits*.
>   For example, \u00A9 matches the copyright symbol (©).

Also, I wonder, is this a valid range: `\xf8-\u037d`  (according to asp.net minify tool) ?
You might want to try `\u00f8-\u037d` instead.
(Maybe add `\xf8-\xff` to compensate for differences between the upper half of localized code-pages versus Unicode in that region.)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is correct. However, in the future, you can use [www.debuggex.com](http://www.debuggex.com/?re=%5B%5E-._0-9A-Za-z%5Cxb7%5Cxc0-%5Cxd6%5Cxd8-%5Cxf6%5Cxf8-%5Cu037d%5Cu37f-%5Cu1fff%5Cu200c-%5Cu200d%5Cu203f%5Cu2040%5Cu2070-%5Cu218f%5D&flags=&str=), which will immediately highlight the error for you and give you an explanation.

In this case, `There must be exactly four hex digits after "\u"`.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Nice plug for [your](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15819919/where-can-i-find-unit-tests-for-regular-expressions-in-multiple-languages) cool tool.     Out of curiosity, what about that `\xf8-\u037d` range? Shouldn't it catch that to? My understanding is that 'ascii' is often a localized codepage (like 'win1252') and (apart from the lower half) not identical to Unicode (unless the webpage was served as unicode). But I might be wrong..

Comment: Apologies for the delayed reply. Both escape sequences represent 16-bit code points. Thus, as long as the first code point is smaller than the second, the range is valid. For much more info, see http://inimino.org/~inimino/blog/javascript_cset